# Move all non-blank rows to the top of the ws fast

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to move all non blank rows to the top of my worksheet (actually to the top of an `Autofilter`).

I have realised that simply deleting the blank rows is quite slow, and that a faster alternative is assigning the range to a variant.

I have come up with this code, however for some reason it's losing some of the rows:

```
Public Sub CompactRows(ByRef ws As Worksheet)
    Dim a As Variant
    With ws
        a = .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow
        .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Clear
        .AutoFilter.Range.Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(a), .UsedRange.Columns.Count) = a
    End With
End Sub
```

So if I have 1000 rows, separated by blank rows, creating 100 sub-ranges, after the function ends I only have 100 rows (the other 900 are lost).

I noticed that in this case `Ubound(a)` also returns 100. My theory is that it copies only the first row in each sub-range but I'm not sure. Any solution to this, or another faster alternative to achieve the same result quickly will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just sort the rows from VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting it to find the blanks shouldn't affect the rest of the rows - they should stay in the correct order. However, if you end up sorting on more than one column because what constitutes a blank row is more complicated, then it could happen.

This procedure takes a range with no headers. It adds a column with the original sort, sorts the range, deletes the blanks, then resorts the range back to the original way.

```
Public Sub CompactRows(ByRef rng As Range)

    Dim rNew As Range

    'Put the row in a column so you can sort it
    'back to the original way later
    With rng.Offset(, rng.Columns.Count).Resize(, 1)
        .Formula = "=ROW()"
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

    'Make a range that includes the sort column
    Set rNew = rng.Resize(, rng.Columns.Count + 1)

    'Sort on the first column to get all the blanks together
    rNew.Sort rNew.Cells(1), xlAscending, , , , , , xlNo
    'Assume a blank in column 1 is a blank row - delete them all in one shot
    rNew.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    'Resort the range on the sort column
    rNew.Sort rNew.Cells(rNew.Columns.Count), xlAscending, , , , , , xlNo
    'Delete the sort column
    rNew.Cells(rNew.Columns.Count).EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As ExcelHero said, you can sort the rows from Excel. But this will change the order of your non-empty rows. IF you want to remove blank rows but keep the order of your data, you can apply this macro:

```
Sub removeEmptyRows()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In UsedRange.Rows
        If Application.CountA(r) = 0 Then r.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```